# What is a fast way to replace identical branches inside nested structures with references?

Tags: duplicates, perl

Is there a readily available module for Perl that could scan an arbitrarily big nested structure of hashes and arrays and replace all identical branches (those that, for example, [`Test::Deep::cmp_deeply`](http://p3rl.org/Test%3a%3aDeep#ok-cmp_deeply-got-expected-name-) would say 'ok' about) with references to only a single value?

I have my own solution for this problem already, but I would prefer to use existing fast XS module if it is available.

Example of original structure as shown by [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDumper):

```
$VAR1 = {
    'other_elems' => [
        {
            'sub_elements' => [
                {'id' => 333},
                {
                    'props' => ['attr5', 'attr6'],
                    'id'    => 444
                }
            ],
            'other_key_for_attrs' => ['attr1', 'attr5'],
            'id'                  => 222
        },
        {
            'sub_elements' => [{'id' => 333}],
            'id'           => 111
        }
    ],
    'elems' => [
        {
            'attrs' => ['attr1', 'attr5'],
            'id'    => 1
        },
        {
            'parent' => 3,
            'attrs'  => ['attr1', 'attr5'],
            'id'     => 2
        },
        {
            'attrs' => ['attr5', 'attr6'],
            'id'    => 3
        },
        {
            'attrs' => ['attr5', 'attr6'],
            'id'    => 4
        }
    ]
};
```

Example of expected result structure:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'other_elems' => [
        {
            'sub_elements' => [
                {'id' => 333},
                {
                    'props' => ['attr5', 'attr6'],
                    'id'    => 444
                }
            ],
            'other_key_for_attrs' => ['attr1', 'attr5'],
            'id'                  => 222
        },
        {
            'sub_elements' =>
              [$VAR1->{'other_elems'}[0]{'sub_elements'}[0]],
            'id' => 111
        }
    ],
    'elems' => [
        {
            'attrs' => $VAR1->{'other_elems'}[0]{'other_key_for_attrs'},
            'id'    => 1
        },
        {
            'parent' => 3,
            'attrs'  => $VAR1->{'other_elems'}[0]{'other_key_for_attrs'},
            'id'     => 2
        },
        {
            'attrs' =>
              $VAR1->{'other_elems'}[0]{'sub_elements'}[1]{'props'},
            'id' => 3
        },
        {
            'attrs' =>
              $VAR1->{'other_elems'}[0]{'sub_elements'}[1]{'props'},
            'id' => 4
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any such module, but the task sounded like fun so I will give you my implementation for comparison's sake. Note that this has a rather large inefficiency since it duplicates the serialization work as it traverses the data structure (could be re-written to traverse from the leaf elements up, building up the serialized string as it goes).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my $hash = {
    foo => ['bar', {baz => 3}],
    qux => [{baz => 3}, ['bar', {baz => 3}]]
};

{   
    local $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
    local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
    local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;

    my %seen_branches;
    my @refs_to_check = \(values %$hash);
    while (my $ref = shift @refs_to_check) {
        my $serial = Dumper($$ref);
        if (my $existing = $seen_branches{$serial}) {
            $$ref = $existing;
        } else {
            $seen_branches{$serial} = $$ref;
            if (ref($$ref) eq 'ARRAY') {
                push @refs_to_check, \(@{$$ref});
            } elsif (ref($$ref) eq 'HASH') {
                push @refs_to_check, \(values %{$$ref});
            }
        }
    }
}

print Dumper $hash;
```